# Setting log4j.rootLogger=OFF in one class configuration, will cause log crash in another class

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Setting log4j.rootLogger=OFF in one class configuration, will cause another class to not log.
I have two sample classes: LogCrasher and MainLogger. This two classes are configured to log some test logs. Each class have it's own configuration file. LogCrasher was called from MainLogger. When log4j.rootLogger in LogCrashers log4j configuration file is set to INFO, WARN... there is no problem with logging, but if we set it to OFF, then MainLogger will not output logs anymore. 
How can be this fixed, to isolate one class logger form another.

MainLogger.java

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

public class MainLogger {
    private static String LOG_PROPS = "mainlogger.properties";
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainLogger.class);

    static {
        PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch(LOG_PROPS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainLogger mainLogger = new MainLogger();
        try {
            mainLogger.doLogging();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            logger.error(t.getMessage(), t);
        }
    }

    public void doLogging() {
        logger.info("Before calling log crasher.");
        printTestLog();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                LogCrasher logCrasher = new LogCrasher();
                logCrasher.printTestLog();
            }
        }).start();

        logger.info("After calling log crasher.");

        printTestLog();
    }

    private void printTestLog() {
        int counter = 0;
        while (++counter < 5) {
            logger.info("Counter: " + counter);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.info("printTestLog sleeper thread interupted: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LogCrasher.java

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

public class LogCrasher {
    private static String LOG_PROPS = "logcrasher.properties";
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogCrasher.class);

    static {
        PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch(LOG_PROPS);
    }

    public void printTestLog() {
        int counter = 0;
        while (++counter < 5) {
            logger.info("Counter: " + counter);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.info("printTestLog sleeper thread interupted: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

logcrasher.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=OFF, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Rirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logcrasher.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

mainlogger.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Rirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=mainlogger.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Why do you think logging configurations apply to a single class?

Comment: I want to isolate one class logger from another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot define 2 log4j properties files like this. Log4j framework will load and consider only one, which ever it will find first in the classpath.

Now for the solution part of your problem, you cannot have separate logging scheme at class level like this, but you can have separate logging scheme at package level.
Now considering your 2 classes are in different packages, you can have your log4j.properties as below.
`log4j.logger.com.stackoverflow.meta` will get applied to all classes in `com.stackoverflow.meta` package, and `log4j.logger.com.stackoverflow.code` for all classes in `com.stackoverflow.code` package.

Like this you now have now control over package level logging.

```
log4j.logger.com.stackoverflow.meta=OFF, file, stdout
log4j.logger.com.stackoverflow.code=DEBUG, file, stdout

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Rirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=mainlogger.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Thanks for your good answer. Also another question. Is there a logger, which not uses factory/singleton approach?

Comment: I think you are getting this question because of answer from "anonymous" user, so that would be better person to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The `log4 framework` uses the `factory/singleton` approach... so if you reload a new `config` in 1 class, all classes in the same `class loader` should see that `config` as if it is the 1 true `live config`.

What you need to do is encapsulate the logging behavior you need at a `package/class` level and you'll see the effects when you call `Logger.getLogger()`. With the newer versions of `apache log4j`, you can call `LogManger.getLogger()` with `no args` to get the logger for the `current class` (makes it easy to define in all class files).

Then since you can have a different series of `loggers` and `appenders`, as well as set appenders to cascade through differnt loggers, you shouldn't need more than 1 config file.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I need more then one config. This problem happens on loading plugins, if plugin will set rootLogger to OFF, then main class will not output logs.

Comment: @Art: Can you change your config so that each class that is logging uses their own appenders and loggers or series or appenders and loggers, rather than the root. I also can't see why you'd want to shut down the root logger. I'd need more details of your use case to understand what an idea config for you would be, but you can do a lot with log4j configs. I personally run an xml config where I read in JVM params to dynamically set thresholds on some of the thresholds for different loggers to adjust behavior from my local pc to dev to uat and then prd.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not need to turn of root logger, but I want to safe main logger from loaded plugin, which can have config like that.